# Why every object of a Galois category is the sum of its connected subobjects?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a Galois category.
    Let $X$ be an object of $C$.
    In Lenstra's notes on Galois theory for schemes, it is written that if $X$ is not connected then there is a subobject $Y \longrightarrow X$ with $\emptyset = F(0) \not= F(Y) \not= F(X)$.
    Using G3 one then finds $Z$ such that $X$ may be identified with $Y \coprod Z$ so that $F(X)$ is, by G5, equal to the disjoint union of $F(Y)$ and $F(Z)$.
    Arguing by induction on $\# F(X)$ one concludes that every object of $C$ is the sum of its connected subobjects (page 40).

I see why every object is the sum of connected subobjects but I don't understand why every object is the sum of all its connected subobjects.

Comment: Shouldn't the induction solve your problem? The claim ought to be clear for $\#F(X)=1$ and then the induction step should just let you do this all the way up.

Comment: @KReiser Yes, we can prove by induction that an object is the sum of (its ?) connected subobjects.

Comment: Okay, so where's your confusion? Your post states that "I don't understand why every object is the sum of all its connected subobjects." But then your comment says "Yes, we can prove by induction that an object is the sum of (its ?) connected subobjects." Can you be more specific about what you have trouble with?

Comment: @KReiser I don't understand why $X = \coprod_A A$ where the coproduct is over all the subobjects of $X$. I see that $X$ is coproduct of some subobjects of $X$, but why all subobjects ? It is certainly trivial.

Comment: For every connected subobject $B$, you can write a decomposition $X=B\coprod\cdots$. So $\coprod_A A\cong B\coprod \cdots$. Can you show that $B$ must be one of $A$ (up to isomorphism)?

Comment: @KReiser I agree with you to say that for every subobject $B$ we have a decomposition $X = B \coprod \cdots$. I don't understand why $X \simeq \coprod_A A$.  I try to prove this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question, the central claim is that any decomposition uses all the connected subobjects of $X$. In other words:

> **Claim:** In a Galois category $(\mathcal{C}, F)$, given connected objects $B_1, B_2, \dots, B_k, B$ and a monomorphism $u: B \hookrightarrow B_1 \coprod B_2 \coprod \dots \coprod B_k=:X,$ $u$ factors for a unique $j$ as an isomorphism $u_j: B \stackrel{\simeq}\rightarrow B_j$ followed by the canonical map $B_j \rightarrow X$ (hence, $B$ and $B_j$ are equal as subobjects of $X$).

To show that, first berve the following

> **Observation:** In a Galois category,  fibered products distribute over finite coproducts.

*Proof of Observation:* Enough to argue for binary coproducts. So consider $X \rightarrow Y, Z_1 \coprod Z_2\rightarrow Y$ in $\mathcal{C}$. We want to show that the canonical map $$can:(X\times_Y Z_1) \coprod (X\times_Y Z_2)\rightarrow X\times_Y (Z_1\coprod Z_2)$$ is an isomorphism. The fiber functor $F$ commutes with fiber products and finite coproducts (by (G4), (G5)), so in $\mathbf{Set}$ we obtain the same canonical map
$$F(can):(FX\times_{FY} FZ_1) \coprod (FX\times_{FY} FZ_2)\rightarrow FX\times_{FY} (FZ_1\coprod FZ_2)$$
which is an isomorphism of sets (this is a (trivial) property of $\mathbf{Set}$). By (G6), it follows that $can$ is itself an isomorphism. $\square$

Now the claim follows rather formally:

*Proof of Claim:* Given $u$ as in the claim, one can "refine B by the decomposition of $X$," i.e. look at

$$B=B \times_X X=B \times_X(B_1 \coprod B_2 \coprod \dots \coprod B_k)=(B\times_X B_1) \coprod (B \times_X B_2) \coprod \dots \coprod (B \times_X B_k).$$

Since $B$ is connected, it follows that one of the pieces $B \times_X B_j$ equals to $B$ as a subobject of $B$, an all the other are equal to $\emptyset$. That is, the canonical map $B\times_X B_j \rightarrow B$ is invertible, and $u_j$ is then obtained by considering its inverse followed by the second canonical map,
$$u_j: B \stackrel{\simeq}\leftarrow B\times_X B_j \hookrightarrow B_j.$$
(To see that $u_j$ is in fact an isomorphism, note that it is monic and $B, B_j$ are connected.) $\square$